# Subsonic and CSLA.NET

Tags: subsonic, csla

Can SubSonic be used with CSLA.NET? Has anyone tried this. From my understanding

- SubSonic is a DAL
- CSLA.NET is a BAL (BLL)

I can't seem to find any information on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SubSonic could be used as a DAL. I had a some trouble implementing a DAL at first when I was learning CSLA just because there is little documentation on this subject. I would recommend checking out our [templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx). We have  a complete working Parameterized SQL or Stored Procedure driven DAL. This is all sub templated out so you could easily implement or copy 8 sub templates and change it to use SubSonic and all of your BO's would now be driven by SubSonic in a very small amount of time.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you will need to kludge around some issues to get CSLA to talk via your own DAL - see http://www.lhotka.net/Article.aspx?area=4&id=2e6468d6-9a02-4f0e-a31c-a7eecc268e1b

There is also a more detailed forum discussion on the subject at http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/thread/3714.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic is pretty well encapsulated so you can use it with just about anything.  You can put the DAL that SubSonic generates in its own separate class library and/or namespace.

No experience with the CSLA.NET side of things.